# java-graphql use namespace type resolver with inner class cant access

Tags: graphql, graphql-java, spring-graphql

Using a scheme with such set

```
type Query {
    client: ClientQuery!
}

type ClientQuery {
    info(clientId: String): Client
}

type Client {
    gender: String
    name: String
}
```

i have same reoslver for it

```
@Controller
class ClientResource {
   @QueryMapping
   fun client(@ContextValue clientId: Long): ClientQuery {
        val currentClient = getClient(clientId)
        log.info { "Current client $currentClient" }
        return query
    }

  @Controller
  class ClientQuery {
      @SchemaMapping(typeName = "ClientQuery ", field = "info")
      fun info(@Argument cleintId: String): Client {
         // some manipulation
        return Client()
      }
  }

}
```

but i want use `inner class ClientQuery` instead of `class ClientQuery` but when i use `inner class` when calling the graphiql request`{client{info(clientId:"1"){gender,name}}}` in the response comes null and I don’t see that there was a call to the inner class
Maybe there is something that I am missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please verify you haven't made a typo in your **@Argument cleintId** , since in your graphiql request you mention you are sending **clientId:"1"**.

Also you could try putting both mappings at the same level inside the Controller:

```
   @QueryMapping
   fun client(@ContextValue clientId: Long): ChatQuery {
        val currentClient = getClient(clientId)
        log.info { "Current client $currentClient" }
        return query
    }

   @SchemaMapping(typeName = "ClientQuery ", field = "info")
   fun info(@Argument cleintId: String): Client {
      // some manipulation
     return Client()
   }
```

Comment: yes, everything is right here thanks, I want to find out more whether it is possible in principle to use a construction similar to the inner class inside the main graphql resolver

Answer (score 0):

Аfter the offer of "Julio César Estravis"
I made some changes that also take "inner class" in code

```
@Controller
class ClientResource {
  private val query = ClientQuery()

  @QueryMapping
  fun client(@ContextValue clientId: Long): ClientQuery {
    val currentClient = getClient(clientId)
    log.info { "Current client $currentClient" }
    return query
  }

  inner class ClientQuery

  @SchemaMapping(typeName = "ClientQuery ", field = "info")
  fun info(@Argument cleintId: String): Client {
    // some manipulation
    return Client()
  }
}
```